# SOQL - Viewing Parent Object field

Tags: soql

A fresher question.

I am unable to view the data either in the developer console or in the Eclipse IDE for the following query.

Parent : Case
Child : Case_Search_Worklog__c

```
SELECT Case__r.Case_Co_Owner__r.Email FROM Case_Search_Worklog__c WHERE ID = 'a3Km000000002xEEAQ'
```

In Dev Console, I am getting an output like this.

[object Object]

Can someone tell what should I do to view the column data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing something similar to?

```
Case_Search_Worklog__c workLog = [SELECT Case__r.Case_Co_Owner__r.Email 
                                  FROM Case_Search_Worklog__c 
                                  WHERE ID = 'a3Km000000002xEEAQ'];
System.debug(workLog.Case__r.Case_Co_Owner__r.Email);
```

You can always try out your query in the <kbd>Query Editor</kbd> tab in the Dev Console:

[image]